# How to update parent component with a state that has updated within a custom hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm not sure if this has been asked before. I couldn't find anything after googling.

I have a parent component which basically has a button which when clicked will open a modal.

Inside the modal, there is a form which makes a post-call to an API. If the post-call is successful, I need the modal to be closed. I'm experimenting custom hooks to achieve this.

Below is my code:

**Custom Hook**

```
type savedHook = {
    saved: boolean,
    loading: boolean,
    error: string,
    saveSearch: (search: any) => void,
    showNewModal: boolean,
    setShowNewModal: (boolean) => void
};

export const useSaveSearch = () : savedSearchHook => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [saved, setSaved] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState('');
    const [showNewSaveSearch, setNewShowSearch] = useState(false);

    const saveSearch = async (search: any) => {
        setLoading(true);

        fetch('my api', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(search),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then((data) => {
            setSaved(true);
            setLoading(false);
            setShowNewModal(false);
        }).catch((error) => {
            setError(error);
            setLoading(false);
        });
    }

    const setShowNewModal = (show: boolean) => {
        setNewShowSearch(show);
    }


    return {
        error,
        loading,
        saveSearch,
        saved,
        setShowNewModal,
        showNewModal: showNewSaveSearch
    }

}
```

**Modal**

```
export default function SaveSearch({isOpen, onDismiss}) {
    const { state } = useSearch();
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const { loading, saved, error, saveSearch } = useSaveSearch();

    const handleSave = () => {
        saveSearch({
            name,
            query: state.query,
            type: state.type
        });
    }

    return (
      <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onDismiss={onDismiss}>
        <div>
          <span>Save Search ({state.type})</span>
          <IconButton styles={iconButtonStyles} iconProps={{iconName: 'Cancel'}} onClick={onDismiss} />
        </div>
        <div>
              <TextField label="Name" autoFocus value={name} onChange={(e, value) => setName(value)} />
                {loading && <Spinner size={SpinnerSize.small} />}
              <DefaultButton text="Save" onClick={handleSave} iconProps={{iconName: 'Save'}} disabled={name.length === 0 || loading} />


        </div>

      </Modal>
    )
  }
```

**Parent Component**

```
export default function ParentComponent() {
   const { showNewModal, setShowNewModal } = useSaveSearch();

   return (
     <div>
       {<SaveSearch isOpen={showNewModal} onDismiss={() => setShowNewModal(false)} />}
        <PrimaryButton text="Save Search" onClick={() => setShowNewModal(true)} iconProps={{iconName: 'Save'}} />
    </div>
   );
}
```

The problem I'm facing is, to open the modal, I'm calling setShowNewModal from the parent component which works fine. But after the save function, I'm calling setShowNewModal from the hook which doesn't get updated in the parent component.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good if you could provide a working example.

Anyways, if I'm correct, the `setShowNewModal(false);` inside the `saveSearch` method of `useSaveSearch` custom hook should close the `Modal`, right?
Well, if that's the case, inside `setShowNewModal` you just call `setNewShowSearch`. Then, the value of `setNewShowSearch` is returned for a property named `showNewModal`, but inside the `Modal`, when you write the following line:

```
const { loading, saved, error, saveSearch } = useSaveSearch();
```

You don't consider the `showNewModal` property, in the deconstructor. Maybe I'm missing something in the flow: that's why I was asking for a working demo.

Anyways, going back to the issue: inside the `Modal` component you could just pass the `onDismiss` method:

```
const { loading, saved, error, saveSearch } = useSaveSearch(onDismiss);
```

And inside the `useSaveSearch` custom hook, just call the `onDismiss` parameter, which will call the callback `() => setShowNewModal(false)` defined in the `Parent` component.

Comment: Thanks, mate. Passing onDismiss from parent to child component was my backup option. And I did use it. Removed all hook logics from my code as I didn't have much time to investigate what was going wrong. But I'll have to revisit hooks once I get some free time. Appreciate your help. I'll post a working example later.

Comment: Hooks are quite easy once you got the concept; they are easier than the legacy lifecycle methods, but maybe a little more complicated to understand. They are just a JavaScript example of the "Cause/Effect"